# Is "having" necessary here

Tags: grammar, spoken-english

Today I heard a sentence:

> Do you want more potatoes peeled.

But I have always used it as:

> Do you want **having** more potatoes peeled.

Which one is grammartical?
Please explain with examples.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you learn that your second example with "having" is OK?.

Comment: @FumbleFingers could you please explain with example. I'm a non native learner.

Comment: This has been asked about before. One earlier question about the issue is [*What's the diffence between “I want you **to go** to sleep” and “I want you **going** to sleep”*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/7063/whats-the-diffence-between-i-want-you-to-go-to-sleep-and-i-want-you-going-to/23435)

Comment: Your first example (a concealed passive) is acceptable, Also acceptable is "Do you want more potatoes peeling?" But your example with "having" is completely ungrammatical because "want" does not license such gerund-participial complements.

Comment: In unusual / contrived contexts, the continuous form *can* be idiomatically "okay". For example, *When I get back from the pub I don't want you sitting up waiting for me.* But strictly speaking that's probably just a slightly "reduced" form of underlying *...I don't want you **to be** sitting up waiting for me.*

Comment: "Want" can licence certain gerund-participial complements, e.g. "I want them standing when the PM arrives" / "I don't want you bringing your dog with you".

Comment: @BillJ: "Do you want more potatoes peeling?" suggests that peeling is done **by** potatoes, not **to** potatoes. "Do you want more potatoes peeled?" makes more sense for that reason. Or did you mean "Do you want more potato peeling?"? In that case, _potato_ no longer is a noun but an adjective, and it roughly means ""Do you want more peeling of potatoes?"

Comment: It doesn't suggest that at all. It’s a ‘concealed’ passive, where the natural interpretation is "Do you want more potatoes peeling (by someone)".  "Do you want more potatoes peeled" is an alternative. In your last example, "potato-peeling" is a compound noun consisting of noun + deverbal noun in _ing_ (cf. also "shop-lifting", "star-gazing", "town-planning" etc). I suggest you get your facts right.